# ping timing out from remote server to home box

Tags: ssh, remote-access, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to connect from a remote ec2 instance to my home box over ssh and it's hanging (no error, just hanging), and I'm not sure why. I am successfully connecting over ssh from my home box to the instance.

I attempted to test whether the ip I had for the home box was correct; using the home box **local** ip address, I was able to connect remotely from another box on the same LAN. However, using the **public** ip address, it still hangs, so I assume it's related to some external connection restrictions, not specific to ssh (as shown by the socket.io example above). What sort of restrictions could be causing my home box to hang on external connections?

EDIT: I've seen [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/549226/ssh-into-linux-box-from-ec2?rq=1), but does that mean my LAN's router has to be configured to accept ssh/ping/socket connections too? I thought that would just be allowed by default.

EDIT: Checked iptables and even set to allow all connections for a second; didn't work. The simplest possible test, just pinging the IP from an external source, also hangs. The home box is running Arch Linux.

EDIT: I can ssh/ping another box on the same network, which is strange. The other box is connected by ethernet instead of my home box's wifi connection; would that matter?

Comment: The router had to be configured for IP forwarding.  Each service such as ssh and ping has it's own port that would need to be forwarded.

Comment: I would think so, except I just checked and another computer on the same network connected by ethernet is able to be ssh'd and ping'd.

Comment: Can you ping it from another internal IP address? Firewall on "home box" blocking ping?

Comment: It yells about "icmp open socket: Operation not permitted" when I ping it instead of hanging, and I can ssh successfully from another internal ip address to the home box.

Answer (score 1):

My university network applies additional security restrictions on wireless connections, including a firewall which drops connections on all incoming ports. Case closed.